# Data Truncated for Column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE float_one, float_two, my_result NUMERIC(7,2)    
my_result = CONVERT(float_one/float_two, DECIMAL(7,2));
```

In this mysql query, I do this type of operation in a stored procedure, but the Linux environment phpmyadmin throws the following warning:

> Note: #1265 Data truncated for column 'float_one' at row 5

Does anyone have an idea how can I solve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `float_sample` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `first_number` float(10,3) default NULL,
      `second_number` float(10,3) default NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `float_sample` (`id`, `first_number`, `second_number`) 
VALUES    (1, 2.900, 1.900),    (2, 3.100, 22.100);
```

and the procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS float_test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE float_test(IN my_ID INT)  

BEGIN
DECLARE first_float, second_float DECIMAL(10,3);

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT `first_number`, `second_number`
        FROM `float_sample`
        WHERE `id` = my_ID;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN myCursor;
my_loop:LOOP
    FETCH myCursor INTO first_float, second_float;

    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;

END LOOP my_loop;
CLOSE myCursor;

-- SELECT first_float, second_float;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and the result

```
1 70 10:41:36    CALL mytests.float_test(1) 0 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s):
1265 Data truncated for column 'first_float' at row 2
1265 Data truncated for column 'second_float' at row 2  0.032 sec
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the the value of float_one at the time of conversion ???

Note this example from MySQL 5.5.12 in Windows

```
mysql> select convert(20000,decimal(7,2));
+-----------------------------+
| convert(20000,decimal(7,2)) |
+-----------------------------+
|                    20000.00 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select convert(200000,decimal(7,2));
+------------------------------+
| convert(200000,decimal(7,2)) |
+------------------------------+
|                     99999.99 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                               |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'convert(200000,decimal(7,2))' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It may be possible that data was truncated if a number bigger than 99999.99 was in float_one. Perhaps, mysql was converting float_one and float_two to DECIMAL(7,2) individually before performing division. Try using DECIMAL(10,2) or greater to accommodate large values.

**UPDATE 2011-07-25 15:05 EDT**

There are definite truncation problem going on here

According to [MySQL Reference Manual Page 442 Paragraphs 2,3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596002653)

> DECIMAL and NUMERIC values are stored as strings, rather than as
>   binary floating point numbers, in order to preserve the decimal
>   precision of those numbers. One character is used for each digit of
>   the value, the deciaml point (if scale > 0) and the - sign (for
>   negative numbers). If the scale is 0, DECIMAL and NUMERIC values
>   contain no decimal point or fractional part.
>
> The maximum range of DECIMAL and NUMERIC is the same as for DOUBLE,
>   but the actual range for the given DECIMAL or NUMERIC column can be
>   constrainted by the precision and scale for a give column, When such a
>   column is assigned a value with more digits following the decimal
>   point than are allowed by the specified scale, the value is rounded to
>   that scale. When a DECIMAL or NUMERIC column is assigned a value whose
>   magnitude exceeds the range implied by the specified (or defaulted)
>   precision and scale, MySQL stores the value representing the
>   corresponding endpoint of that range.

You need to accommodate a larger precision and/or scale.

Here is an example as to why

I wrote this stored procedure using your specifications for DECMIAL and NUMERIC.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`NumTest` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test`.`NumTest` (num1 NUMERIC(7,2), num2 NUMERIC(7,2))
BEGIN

  DECLARE float_one,float_two,my_result NUMERIC(7,2);
  DECLARE f1,f2 DOUBLE(7,2);

  SET f1 = num1;
  SET f2 = num2;

  SET float_one = num1;
  SET float_two = num2;

  SELECT f1 / f2;
  SELECT float_one / float_two;
  SELECT CONVERT(float_one / float_two,DECIMAL(7,2));
  SET my_result = CONVERT(float_one / float_two,DECIMAL(7,2));
  SELECT my_result;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I used two values: 290.0 and 14.5 for this test.

Before calling the NumTest stored procedure, I manually calculated 290.0 / 14.5

```
mysql> select 290.0 / 14.5;
+--------------+
| 290.0 / 14.5 |
+--------------+
|     20.00000 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I divided each number by 100, 10000, and 1000000 and tried again

```
mysql> select 2.9 / .145;
+------------+
| 2.9 / .145 |
+------------+
|   20.00000 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select .029 / .00145;
+---------------+
| .029 / .00145 |
+---------------+
|    20.0000000 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select .00029 / .0000145;
+-------------------+
| .00029 / .0000145 |
+-------------------+
|      20.000000000 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far, so good !!! Now for the stored procedure.

```
mysql> call numtest(290.0,14.5);
+-----------+
| f1 / f2   |
+-----------+
| 20.000000 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------------+
| float_one / float_two |
+-----------------------+
|             20.000000 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(float_one / float_two,DECIMAL(7,2)) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                       20.00 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------+
| my_result |
+-----------+
|     20.00 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

So my orignal two numbers work fine. Let's divide them by 100 and try again.

```
mysql> call numtest(2.9,0.145);
+-----------+
| f1 / f2   |
+-----------+
| 19.333333 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------------+
| float_one / float_two |
+-----------------------+
|             19.333333 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+---------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(float_one / float_two,DECIMAL(7,2)) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                       19.33 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------+
| my_result |
+-----------+
|     19.33 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                   |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'num2' at row 2 |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

WAIT, we lost some precision. What happened ??? How did this happen ??? You need to accommodate more decmial digits (> 2)

**UPDATE 2011-07-25 17:37 EDT**

I substituted (7,2) with (10,7) in the stored procedure and got back the proper precision

```
mysql> call numtest(2.9,0.145);
+----------------+
| f1 / f2        |
+----------------+
| 20.00000000000 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+-----------------------+
| float_one / float_two |
+-----------------------+
|        20.00000000000 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+----------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT(float_one / float_two,DECIMAL(10,7)) |
+----------------------------------------------+
|                                   20.0000000 |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

+------------+
| my_result  |
+------------+
| 20.0000000 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your stored procedure just loops through the rows - it does not 'save the data' anywhere and you have commented out the `select`:

> -- SELECT first_float, second_float;

Yes you are getting warnings when the `float(10,3)` fields are converted to `decimal(10,3)`. Whether they are a problem or not depends on what you want to do with the fields.

Is this just a sample of the real code? You may need to post some more...

Comment: it is nothing special about the insert. The code works fine under windows, even with the warnings. Under Linux environment, the insert doesn't take place and I assume that it's the warnings fault. Do you have any idea about how can I solve the warnings? I'm totally stucked.

Comment: The code you have shown *does not do an insert*. It *does not even return any values*. It throws two warnings that seem to be irrelevant, *because whatever you are inserting does not come out of the procedure that generates the warnings*. Show the actual code that "doesn't work" and any error messages that are thrown *by that code*, and we may be able to help you.