# MySQL conversion from float (10,2) to fixed(10,2)

Tags: mysql, floating-point

I have a database that contains financial data stored as floats. Naturally, this can present a real issue at random times (eg, when there is an exact value that cannot be approximated closely enough with a floating-point algorithm).

**My question is**:

- Will using  `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY field fixed(10,2)` preserve the fixed value that is currently shown by MySQL when you select the field?
- Is there any possibility that the value would be something other than that?

Comment: Yes. There is a possibility that the value would be different than that. But you "have to" change it to decimal to avoid issues in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### **BAD NEWS : I do not think the value will be preserved !!!**

[I wrote this post (July 25, 2011)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4094/877) showing how sensitive floating point numbers are to conversions.

#### **GOOD NEWS : Here is how you can safely compare the data conversion:**

If your table has these characteristics

- table is called `moneytable`
- field you wish to convert is called `moneyfield`
- primary key is called `moneyid`

Then run these commands:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS moneytabletest;
CREATE TABLE moneytabletest LIKE moneytable;
ALTER TABLE moneytabletest MODIFY moneyfield fixed(10,2);
INSERT INTO moneytabletest SELECT * FROM moneytable;
SELECT A.moneyid,A.moneyfield olddata,B.moneyfield newdata
FROM moneytable A LEFT JOIN moneytabletest B USING (moneyid)
WHERE A.moneyfield <> B.moneyfield;
```

**Here is the bottom line:** *If any rows come back* from the `LEFT JOIN` query, the conversion will be bad. You will have to modify the definition of `moneyfield`, reload  the `moneytabletest` table, and run the `LEFT JOIN` query again and again until no rows come back from the `LEFT JOIN` query. Once zero(0) rows come back, you will know what conversion will be safe.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks Rolando; I ended up using a similar but simpler method to do a convert and compare. I will add it as a separate answer.

Comment: @BryanAgee : Looking forward to seeing your answer !!!

Comment: I know this is an old Q&A but since it's still relevant I should mention that it is a bit simpler to test this with `SELECT * FROM moneytable WHERE CONVERT(moneyfield, Decimal(10,2)) != moneyfield;`

Answer (score 5):

Based on Rolando's answer, I came up with an easier method to do a staged conversion, and then compare. In the tables in question, I first added a new field of the same type. The I mirrored the values, ran the conversion, and compared the resulting values. eg, for `Amount float(10,2) NOT NULL` I used:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `AmountStaged` float(10,2) NOT NULL;
UPDATE `table` SET `AmountStaged` = `Amount`;
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `AmountStaged` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE round(`Amount`,2) <> `AmountStaged`;
```

Amazingly, with several tables (some upwards of 30k rows), there was only one value that did not match. Luckily, the deleted flag was set on that particular record, so it was irrelevant anyway. So upon getting the favorable results, the final step was two commands:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP `Amount`;
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `AmountStaged` `Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;
```

**EDIT**:
The zero downtime alternative would be to drop the `AmountStaged` column and convert the `Amount` column, as the conversion *should be* identical to the one we ran to test.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP `AmountStaged`;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has performance implications on a live system vs. Rolando's method, but it was plenty fast under our load

Comment: I like this answer because there is less overall clutter. One table to play with in exchange for adding and dropping a column. In terms of purpose, still apples to apples. +1 !!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answers above!

I have over 130, 972 rows total, there are several float columns with money-like data in.
So today i need to convert those colums to decimal, because we have some troubles with precision.
I used one of solutions above, but the result wasn't exactly that i need, as author said:

> You will have to modify the definition of moneyfield, reload the
>   moneytabletest table, and run the LEFT JOIN query again and again
>   until no rows come back from the LEFT JOIN query. Once zero(0) rows
>   come back, you will know what conversion will be safe.

Another one was lucky and the difference records was marked as deleted...
In my case after this operations:

```
ALTER TABLE `target_table` ADD `dummy_price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL;
UPDATE `target_table` SET `dummy_price` = CAST(`float_price` as DECIMAL(20,2));
SELECT `float_price`, `dummy_price`  FROM `target_table` WHERE round(`float_price`, 2) <> `dummy_price`;
```

... i got 87 rows, that didn't match.
So i decided just update it like this:

```
UPDATE `target_table` 
SET `dummy_price` = round(`float_price`, 2) 
WHERE round( `float_price` , 2 ) <> `dummy_price`
```

Well, after that i got all i need. All rounded data from `float_price` is eq to `dummy_price`, i think its enough.

I think i'll help someone.