# MySQL returns floats rounded

Tags: mysql, floating-point

```
> CREATE TABLE test(foo FLOAT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES(1.2899999);
> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+
| foo  |
+------+
| 1.29 |
+------+
```

While it's obvious that FLOAT is not a precise data type, it is still rounding this data too arbitrarily. Let's check if it's actually able to store it:

```
> ALTER TABLE test MODIFY foo DOUBLE;
> SELECT * FROM test;
+--------------------+
| foo                |
+--------------------+
| 1.2899998426437378 |
+--------------------+
```

Whoops, only the 7th digit got corrupted due format limitations. Is there a way to prevent overzealous rounding in this situation, short of converting the column to DOUBLE?

Answer (score 1):

I hate precision-based issues. I dealt with one before: [Data Truncated for Column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/data-truncated-for-column/4094#4094)

You may have do the ALTER TABLE manually

```
CREATE TABLE test_new LIKE test;
ALTER TABLE test_new MODIFY foo DOUBLE;
INSERT INTO test_new (foo) SELECT CONVERT(foo,DOUBLE) FROM test;
RENAME TABLE test TO test_old,test_new TO test;
DROP TABLE test_old;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test_new LIKE test;
ALTER TABLE test_new MODIFY foo DOUBLE;
INSERT INTO test_new (foo) SELECT CONVERT(foo,DECIMAL(10,7)) FROM test;
RENAME TABLE test TO test_old,test_new TO test;
DROP TABLE test_old;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE test_new LIKE test;
ALTER TABLE test_new MODIFY foo DOUBLE;
INSERT INTO test_new (foo) SELECT FORMAT(foo,7) FROM test;
RENAME TABLE test TO test_old,test_new TO test;
DROP TABLE test_old;
```

Not sure what will happen, but give it a try and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post could be somehow useful for your question - as far as I had experience with till now (even in ERP db we serviced for nearly 5 years) type `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` was almost never used. 
Instead of it all the fields storing values like cost prices, purchase prices, stock item characteristics, warehouse, production, accountance data - always had fixed decimal places count by using i.e. `NUMERIC(20,8)` (MSSQL) which of course in MySQL would be `DECIMAL(20,8)`.
Thus, if any rounding were to be performed, it must have been done (mostly) in the application layer.

Comment: It's for geographical coordinates, so floating point makes more sense here. Definitely not going to use FP anywhere near money:)

Comment: Yeah, those kind of info is not so error-defensive somehow :)